# Allow binding to any data-* attribute on an ember component

Tags: ember.js

I am designing a library whereby I would like to allow the user to supply any `data` attributes they might like.

`{{my-component data-type='hello' data-name='world'}}`

I don't know ahead of time which `data` attributes they might like to bind to so can't add them to the `attributeBindings` array.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `didReceiveAtts` hook of your component:

```
didReceiveAttrs(params){
  let newAttrs = params.newAttrs;
  let attributeBindings = Ember.A();
  Object.keys(newAttrs).forEach((attr)=>{
    if(attr.indexOf('data-')>= 0){
      attributeBindings.pushObject(attr);
    }
  });
  this.set('attributeBindings', attributeBindings);
}
```

Look that [Sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/37465b31f698c1ce47549711a4fd66cd?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

**Updated, after deprecation:**

Since arguments of `didReceiveAttrs` function are deprecated, you need to change the code as the following:

```
didReceiveAttrs(){
  let attributeBindings = Ember.A();
  Object.keys(this).forEach((attr)=>{
    if(attr.indexOf('data-')>= 0){
        attributeBindings.pushObject(attr);
    } 
  });
  this.set('attributeBindings', attributeBindings);
}
```

See [updated twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1639fb3d6f3a91ac7ff50fb7eebb903c?openFiles=components.my-component.js).

Comment: Its worth reading rfc deprecate-component-lifecycle-hook-args .  https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0191-deprecate-component-lifecycle-hook-args.mdhttps://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0191-deprecate-component-lifecycle-hook-args.md

Comment: Thanks. RFC just mention about removing `arguments`. In this case the same code can run with a little modification: Instead of `Object.keys(newAttrs)` just use `Object.keys(this)`.

Comment: unfortunately this is now completely deprecated and cannot be used anymore. If anybody has a bright idea how to solve this with the current ember version I would be very interested in a solution.

Comment: @TeeJaay Thank you for informing me, I've just updated the code.

Comment: I modified this a little `const attributeBindings = [...this.get('attributeBindings')]`
 
If you have already set attributed you want to keep, you should work of a copy.

Works pretty great, thx for that!

Answer (score 0):

I guess after v3.10 you can [do this without any hacks](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/#toc_attributes) with the angle bracket invocation (and if required pass further using the `...attributes`). So in my simplest case it was as simple as

```
<MyComponent data-aaa="bbb"/>
```